# Displaying an SQLite record as part of a TextView (ANDROID)

Tags: android, sqlite

most of my Android questions have been answered from this site, but I have one particular problem that I have not been able to find.  I would like to retrieve various columns of a record from an SQLite database using textview.  For example,

Welcome COLUMN1VALUE, from our records you are living in COLUMN2VALUE and have been living there for COLUMN3VALUE years.

Can anybody point me in the direction of a tutorial or give me an answer for this?  Thanks!

Here is the code:

```
      private void fillData(Uri uri) {
            String[] projection = { TodoTable.COLUMN_COREBELIEF,
                TodoTable.COLUMN_EXPERIENCE1,
                TodoTable.COLUMN_EXPERIENCE2,
                TodoTable.COLUMN_EXPERIENCE3,
                TodoTable.COLUMN_NEWBELIEF,};

        //    String query = "SELECT COLUMN_NEWBELIEF,COLUMN_COREBELIEF,COLUMN_EXPERIENCE1 FROM TodoTable";

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);



    //          Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
                if (cursor != null) {
                      cursor.moveToFirst();
                String s = String.format("Welcome %s, from our records you are living in %s and have been living there for %s years.", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("COLUMN_NEWBELIEF")),  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("COLUMN_COREBELIEF")), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("COLUMN_EXPERIENCE1")));
                textView1.setText(s);


              }



//            mCoreBelief.setText(cursor.getString(cursor
//                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(TodoTable.COLUMN_COREBELIEF)));
//            mExperience1.setText(cursor.getString(cursor
//                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(TodoTable.COLUMN_EXPERIENCE1)));
//            mExperience2.setText(cursor.getString(cursor
//                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(TodoTable.COLUMN_EXPERIENCE2)));
//            mExperience3.setText(cursor.getString(cursor
//                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(TodoTable.COLUMN_EXPERIENCE3)));
//            mNewBelief.setText(cursor.getString(cursor
//                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(TodoTable.COLUMN_NEWBELIEF)));



              // Always close the cursor
              cursor.close();
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so easily by following code:

```
 String query = "SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM mytable";
 Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
 c.moveToFirst();
 String s = String.format("Welcome %s, from our records you are living in %s and have been living there for %s years.", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("col1")),  c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("col2")), c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("col3")));
 txtView.setText(s);
```

Comment: I´m having a few problems implementing your suggestions, because I am using another type of query.  Here is my code (it has been adapted from Vogella´s todo tutorial:

Comment: Fixed it!  I amended your code to apply to mine, will post it in the answer section when I´m allowed to do so.  Really couldn´t find this anywhere else on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Does your SQLite database already exist or do you need guidance on how to manage the entire lifecycle of a SQLite database in Android?

If your database already exists, then @hrehman's answer is enough otherwise Lar Vogel's tutorial at http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html is excellent.

Comment: in fact my app was adapted from the tutorial which you linked to, but I am having problems implementing the suggested code, I pasted the code into the question

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!!  I amended your code as follows:

```
  private void fillData(Uri uri) {
      TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        String[] projection = { TodoTable.COLUMN_COREBELIEF,
            TodoTable.COLUMN_EXPERIENCE1,
            TodoTable.COLUMN_EXPERIENCE2,
            TodoTable.COLUMN_EXPERIENCE3,
            TodoTable.COLUMN_NEWBELIEF,};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null,
            null);
        if (cursor != null) {
          cursor.moveToFirst();
          String s = String.format("Welcome %s, from our records you are living in %s and have been living there for %s years.", 
                  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TodoTable.COLUMN_NEWBELIEF)),  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TodoTable.COLUMN_COREBELIEF)), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TodoTable.COLUMN_EXPERIENCE1)));
          textView1.setText(s);
                      }
```

Thanks!